# How do you data bind to Smith HTML Editor

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm unable to bind directly between Smith HTML editor and the EF model.  When I try to bind this way the HTML editor is blank regardless of the underlying data.

> ```
> <ex:HtmlEditor x:Name="Editor" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BindingContent="{Binding comment_criticalpath}"/>
> ```

If however, I bind the HTML editor to a textblock, and the textblock to the EF model then the binding works as expected.

> ```
> <ex:HtmlEditor x:Name="Editor" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BindingContent="{Binding Text, ElementName=critpath}"/>
> <TextBlock x:Name="critpath" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding comment_criticalpath}" />
> ```

Is there a way to enable to the binding directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Need to specify two way binding mode when binding directly from the Smith HTML editor to the EF.

Side note: just discovered the WPF Toolkit RichTextBox, far easier to use.